# How to make an existing X11 window OpenGL ready?

Tags: c++, opengl, x11

I can't seem to find an example of creating an OpenGL context off of an existing X11 Window. Every example I find creates a window that is already OpenGL ready by providing the necessary visual attributes (via glXChooseVisual or glXChooseFBConfig). What if I already have an existing window (referenced via Display* and Window) and want to change the Colormap and XVisualInfo for the Window for OpenGL rendering? Think ChoosePixelFormat and SetPixelFormat on Windows when creating an OpenGL context. Is this even possible in X11? Do I have to create a Window that's already ready for OpenGL?

Comment: Why not simply download one of the many open-source libraries that does it for you, and see how they are doing it? Or even better, why not *use* one of those libraries?

Comment: Using an open source library would be the easy approach Joachim ;). You make a good point, but the framework I'm writing can't rely on any 3rd party library for window creation that's cross-platform. I've also looked at the FreeGLUT library to see how they're doing it and even they are creating a window last minute based on your settings. They cache the values you provide for creating a context and then use those values you provided to create the window.

Comment: @RamonGuerrero: I don't think what you are trying to do is possible with the X11 API at all. You can't change the visual of existing windows.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case. No biggy. Time to refactor my code a bit. Thanks derhass!